Reactor doOnError - How to include multiple Exception Types in method parameters
I would like to handle multiple exceptions in the same way in the Controller of a Reactive Spring Boot API.
The idea is to send a HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST as an error response for more than one type of Exception in the business logic.
My method ends something like this:
@PostMapping("/my-api")
public Mono<ResponseEntity<String>> save(@RequestBody JsonNode rawDto) {
    
    return 
        myValidator.validate(rawDto)
           .flatMap(validDto -> 
                      myService.save(validDto))
                         .doOnSuccess(result-> 
                                       new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK))
                           .doOnError(MyValidationException.class, error-> 
                                         new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST))
                           .doOnError(MyBusinessLogicException.class, error-> 
                                         new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST))
                           .doOnError(MyRemoteApiException.class, error-> 
                                         new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST))
                           .doOnError(MyDataConstraintException.class, error-> 
                                         new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)); // and so on
}
                           

I would like to combine multiple exceptions in a single doOnError block.
Something similar to this :
.doOnError(MyValidationException.class 
            | MyBusinessLogicException.class 
            | MyRemoteApiException.class, // and so on
              error-> 
                    new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST))

I am not sure of any way to combine multiple exceptions.
I did not want to use if condition before looking for a better option.
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

As an option, using this overloaded version:
public final Flux<T> doOnError(Predicate<? super Throwable> predicate,
        final Consumer<? super Throwable> onError)

With the Set:
private final Set<Class<?>> errors = Set.of(
    MyValidationException.class, 
    MyBusinessLogicException.class,
    MyRemoteApiException.class,
    MyDataConstraintException.class
)

...

    .doOnSuccess(result -> new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK))
    .doOnError(
        error -> errors.contains(error.getClass()), // <---- now this is one predicate
        error -> new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
)

